# Access the time stamp of a HTTP request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, request, timestamp

Is there a way to access the time stamp of when a HTTP request is sent to a Node.js server?

Something like:

```
app.post('', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.date);   //or
    console.log(req.timestamp);
}
```

I tried out several things and already printed out the whole req object to the console, but didn't find a time stamp attribute. Do I have to send the timestamp manually? I thought it is already part of a HTTP request.

Comment: Curious why not just do `new Date()` on the server side. I know you might want when they "sent" it but it can be valuable to know when you actually got it and also anyone can spoof the date in an HTTP request

Answer (score -6, accepted):

There is **Date** in [request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) that can be used to retrieve timestamp.

If you are using Express-4.x you can use `req.get(headerName)` to get it.

If you are using node http module try to do `console.dir(req.headers)`. If its available you can get it from  `req.headers["Date"]`

This all are valid provided your the timestamp is sent across network from client side. Do also inspect the request (Lets say Chrome Dev tool Network) and check what all headers are sent.

Comment: Already tried `req.headers`. It does not list "Date" When I try `req.headers["Date"]`,it returns "undefined". So I guess it wasn't sent with the HTTP request right?

Comment: Check it once from your browser. Go to development tools (Ideally by pressing F12), go to network tab (in chrome, for other browser find the similar tab) then hit the url. Your req should be listed. Check the headers.

Comment: I don't see any reason why he wouldn't. Client sent request, server server serves request and respond to that. I think it is perfectly alright to check what client (in this case [browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) ) has sent across the network. For further reading on [client-server architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Comment: Many times req is not attached with sending timestamp. OP needs to measure on server side

Comment: @CharlesW. I believe you meant 'timestamp is attached with request.'. If thats the case, you are correct,  please read the last paragraph, Its mentioned there.

Comment: `req.headers["Date"]` is not a standard HTTP header and is not a reliable way to get the request timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Date.now()**
Test on console.log, every time the request is get, the timestamp output is different.

Get Timestamp

```
const timestamp = Date.now();
console.log(Math.floor(timestamp/1000));
//expected output: 1685106503
```

Comment: Note that this does not answer what has been asked. The question clearly does not trust either clocks and wants to verify one against the other.